# cygwin warning when building R package

Tags: r, package

I'm trying to build my own package using Windows. I installed everything I need, and running `R CMD build mypackage` and `R CMD INSTALL mypackage` seem to run fine. when I run the `build` command, though, I get a warning from cygwin:

```
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/Documents and Settings/e_sander/My Documents/mypackage_1.0.tar.gz
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/e_sander/My Documents/mypackage_1.0.tar.gz
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning"turns off this warning. Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
```

I did go to the recommended website, but I don't know much about cygwin or linux so I'm not sure there's anything I need to do. I realize that using the MS-DOS style path is deprecated and not recommended in cygwin, but I'm not sure how to change that, since I'm running Windows and that's the path I need. I also haven't noticed any problems with my package, at least when I install it to my computer (and although I haven't used the tarball, I've opened it and everything looks fine). So here's what I'm trying to figure out:

- Does leaving the path as is affect my package in any way?
- If so, how could it adversely affect my package?
- How do I change the path to make cygwin happy?

Comment: As a far as I know it doesn't affect it a bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is just a warning and it tells you how to disable it.  It doesn't affect anything.  If you want it to go away, run this from your shell:

```
export CYGWIN="nodosfilewarning"
```

Or you could mount `C:` to `/c/` (see `man mount`).

Comment: If you have an R session open (or RStudio open) you need to close and restart the R session. Otherwise the environment variable won't be available to R.

Answer (score 3):

- Does leaving the path as is affect my package in any way?
  - No, it is just a warning.
- If so, how could it adversely affect my package?
  - N/A
- How do I change the path to make cygwin happy?
  - Set the environment variable as the output states.  There are multiple ways to do this; I chose to go with a solution that handles the issue across any invoked environment that parses or inherits from the windows environment by using the ["Rapid Environment Editor"](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about) program to add a `User Variable` named `CYGWIN` with a value `nodosfilewarning`.  But if you wanted you could add it through the control panel using `Add environment variables for your account`.