# install RMySQL on windows

Tags: r

I am trying to install the package RMYSQL on windows.

To do so i followed this tutorial : http://www.ahschulz.de/2013/07/23/installing-rmysql-under-windows/

But i am getting an error when i execute

```
 install.packages(“RMySQL”, type = “source”)
```

In deed R returns me the following :

```
Installing package into ‘D:/Users/quentin/Documents/R/win-library/3.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 165363 bytes (161 Kb) opened URL
downloaded 161 Kb

* installing *source* package 'RMySQL' ...
** package 'RMySQL' correctement décompressé et sommes MD5 vérifiées
checking for $MYSQL_HOME... C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/mysql-5.6.19-win32
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/Program
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Program
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
test: Files: unknown operand
** libs
Avis : this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/Program Files                             (x86)/MySQL/mysql-5.6.19-win32"/include    - I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"
-O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c      
RS-DBI.c -o RS-DBI.o
RS-DBI.c: In function 'RS_na_set':
RS-DBI.c:1219:11: warning: variable 'c' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I"C:/Program Files       (x86)/MySQL/mysql-5.6.19-win32"/include    -   I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -   std=gnu99 -mtune=core2    -c RS-MySQL.c -o RS-MySQL.o
RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_MySQL_fetch':
RS-MySQL.c:657:13: warning: variable 'fld_nullOk' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-       variable]
RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_DBI_invokeBeginGroup':
RS-MySQL.c:1137:30: warning: variable 'val' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_DBI_invokeNewRecord':
RS-MySQL.c:1158:20: warning: variable 'val' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-   variable]
RS-MySQL.c: In function 'RS_MySQL_dbApply':
RS-MySQL.c:1219:38: warning: variable 'fld_nullOk' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-   variable]
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RMySQL.dll tmp.def RS-DBI.o RS-MySQL.o C:/Program    Files (x86)/MySQL/mysql-5.6.19-win32/bin/libmySQL.dll -  Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib    -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
collect2: ld returned 5 exit status
aucune DLL n'a pas été créé
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RMySQL'
* removing 'D:/Users/quentin/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RMySQL'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.0/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l     "D:\Users\quentin\Documents\R\win-library\3.1"    D:\Users\quentin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpOwB1UH/downloaded_packages/RMySQL_0.9-3.tar.gz'    had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RMySQL’ had non-zero exit status
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘D:\Users\quentin\AppData\Local\Temp\2\RtmpOwB1UH\downloaded_packages’
```

I couldn't manage to fix this problem so if someone have an idea.

Comment: Did you add `slash` at the end of the path, `eg: R_LIBS = C:\myRLIB\\` when setting up environment variables for `MYSQL_HOME` and `R_LIBS`. If so remove the extra `slash` at the end of the path and try installing once more.

Comment: No i didn't add any slash at the end of the path

Comment: Try disabling cygwin warning. The [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11958083/cygwin-warning-when-building-r-package) will help you.

Comment: I disabled it but it didn't change anything

Comment: Make sure your MYSQL_HOME environment variable is set correctly. On my system its value is `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6`.  Also look into that directory and its subdirectories and copy any dll files into the bin directory.  Make sure that if you are using 64 bit R that you are using 64 bit MySQL (or 32 bit MySQL with 32 bti R).  Use MySQL from the MySQL site.  Other distributions may or may not work.

Comment: I uninstall and install again each software to be sure all of them are in 32 bit. I did all the step of the tutorial again and checked the dll files are in the bin folder. The MYSQL_HOME value is 'C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6'. But I still have the same error.

Answer (score 0):

i tried all the steps from all the instructions i could get, but still got the same problems as you got.

I finallly solved accidently by follow this code:

```
install.packages('RMySQL')
```

instead of

```
install.packages(“RMySQL”, type = “source”)
```

I cannot explain the reason, but it truly works.

---

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by installing from a .zip file not from .tar.gz.

**Make sure your MYSQL_HOME environment variable is set correctly and libmysql.dll is copied to bin folder!!!**

Run `install.packages('RMySQL')` then when the "Do you want to install from sources..." window pops up select `No`.

Then copy the downloaded binary packages location from console.

Go to Packages -> Install, paste the location into Package archive and click Install.